# How do I move a label and animate the change using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to move a UILabel to the left and animate the movement. The UILabel is created from a storyboard, and has the following constraints:

[image]

But if I try to make the trailing space constant equal to say, 150 instead of 20 to move it to the left, it bounces to the left weirdly for a second then comes back to the middle. So I lowered the priority of the left leading constraint to 900, but the same thing still happened.

So I tried:

```
self.textToReadLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-500.0, 0.0);
```

Which moves it, but if I use an animation with it it slides off screen, slides back on and then rests in the place it should... after all those theatrics.

How exactly would I achieve this?

#### Entirety of what happens when I tap the button to move the label:

```
        self.textHorizontalPlacementConstraint.constant = 150.0;
        self.textHorizontalPlacementConstraint2.constant = -110.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];

        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        animation.duration = 0.5;
        animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        [self.textToReadLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];

        // Change the text
        self.textToReadLabel.text = @"text";
    }
```

#### Video of what it looks like:

http://cl.ly/3l2E401N3Q3h

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from interface builder? Is the label's text center aligned?

Comment: It looks to me like the transaction used to change the text is interfering with your animation, by forcing a layout pass (since the label's content has changed). I will try and reproduce this but in the meantime if you remove the text update, does the positioning work correctly?

Comment: Building a basic sample project based on the code in your question, I get what seems to be the desired effect - the label moves left while the text fades to the new value. Therefore there is probably something else in your project that is causing the problem. You will need to create a minimal example that reproduces the issue to get an answer here.

Comment: I thought I had an easy answer for you, but I see iOS doesnt support the `animator` proxy on NSAutoLayoutConstraint :( what happens if you squeeze `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` between your constant settings and the block?

Answer (score 1):

You can set outlets of your constraints in the Interface Builder and then when you want to animate the change you modify your code as below:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        //Change your constraints from code.
    }];
```

For Eg: if I have a leftSpacing Constraint I can directly change it as below:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        //Change your constraints from code.
        self.leftSpacing.constant = self.leftSpacing.constant+20;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

The above code will animate your view from left to right by 20 points.

**UPDATE:**

Have you tried adding multiple constraints: like spacing value should be less than or equal to say:200 but greater than or equal to 20. I think that may help.

Comment: The question already contains this code. And only the layoutIfNeeded part needs to be inside the animation block.